# How ambari detect a service state

Tags: ambari

I'm adding a new custom service to [Ambari](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Defining+a+Custom+Stack+and+Services).

I have successfully created the service and install it in the Ambari web UI. After starting the master component of my new service, Ambari claims that the master is in stop status, however, the master has been run successfully on the intended node and I can use its API.

I wonder how Ambari checks a component status?

- Does it use the status function which I have provided in the component definition? I don't see logs of calling my status function in the Ambari logs.
- Or does it use the PID file? My component does not have a PID file.

Answer (score 1):

@TailofGodzilla (cool name btw), When I make custom services, I start with existing open source examples, and then finally create management packs.  You can easily reverse engineer these, including the service status function.

I checked 3 of these services (Hue, Elk, NiFi) and all are using PID File with entries for status function and status_params file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I vote up your answer for nice clues you have provided, but let me not accept it, because it does not answer my main question: "How Ambari detect a service state?".

Comment: You have 3 questions,  you should ask 1.  And I answered it:  it uses the status function and the pid file.   Good luck.